# Is it possible to embed a SWT Composite into a JavaFX scene?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, javafx

I know that JavaFX 2.2 provides [FXCanvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas.html) for embedding new JavaFX components into existing SWT Composites. Is it possible to do it the other way around?

My motivation for trying this, is that there are currently some components missing in JavaFX. For example a TreeTable. I want to implement my application in JavaFX, use SWT as a fallback for missing components, and migrate those to JavaFX as soon they are ready.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no - you can not embedd heavy weight (=SWT) into a lightweight container (=FX) - JavaFX will get a TreeTable in FX8

Comment: Any reference supporting this?

Comment: reference for what that there's a TreeTable in FX8 or that one can not embed heavyweight into lightweight?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Tom! Do you mean implementing a clean bridge between both frameworks is impractical, or do you mean it is simply impossible without making major changes in at least one of the frameworks?
TreeTable is one example, but there are several SWT-based widget libraries that I'd have to exclude, if I go full JavaFX.

Comment: @MaxHohenegger: to my understanding it's technically impossible to embed a heavy weight toolkit into a light weight one without having troubles e.g. with z-ordering (in FX you get even bigger problems because one can rotate, ... stuff) - remember what happens when mixing Swing & AWT components!

Comment: @Baz although Swing has some support for mixing Heavy-Weight and Light-Weight components http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html I think this does not work that easy for JavaFX because of the whole SceneGraph with all its transformations going on. I talked to Steve Northover sometime ago and if I recap appropiately he said by then that it's not possible

For the TreeTable that's announced somewhere on the JavaFX blog and the code is already in the FX8 repo and will be shipped with it.